# Core Animation Warning: "uncommitted CATransaction"

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, quartz-core, catransaction

I am getting the following warning with Device only:

```
CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; created by:
0   QuartzCore                          0x3763c65d <redacted> + 220
1   QuartzCore                          0x3763c541 <redacted> + 224
2   QuartzCore                          0x3763fe2f <redacted> + 30
3   QuartzCore                          0x3763b9bf <redacted> + 318
4   QuartzCore                          0x3763b87b <redacted> + 50
5   QuartzCore                          0x3763b80b <redacted> + 538
6   MyApp                              0x000df597 -[CommonClass orangeGradient:] + 382
7   MyApp                              0x000f70e1 -[HomeViewController updateStatusBar] + 1700
8   MyApp                              0x000f61bd -[HomeViewController statusRecieved] + 224
9   MyApp                              0x000cd323 -[CommonClass statusReceivedFromServer] + 142
10  MyApp                              0x000d833d -[CommonClass accountStatus] + 7416
11  Foundation                          0x35a3767d <redacted> + 972
12  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x35c9a311 <redacted> + 308
13  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x35c9a1d8 thread_start + 8
```

My Method that is on top of the stack is as follows:

```
- (void)orangeGradient: (UILabel *)fillLabel {
@synchronized([CommonClass class]) {
CAGradientLayer * gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.frame = fillLabel.bounds;
gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColorFromRGB(0xfbb250) CGColor],(id)[UIColorFromRGB(0xf47c2a) CGColor], nil];
[fillLabel.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
}
}
```

Any idea on why is this coming, and how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you calling orangeGradient under UIVIewAnimation or NSOperation?

Comment: calling the method directly from some other class... is that NSOperation?

Comment: If you using performSelector on Thread then it is NSOperation. Basically this problem happens when NSOperation completes before CoreAnimation is done performing. There must be some relation between these two class in somewhere in your code you need to figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `orangeGradient:` is called from a background thread. Core Animation groups all changes into CATransactions. Usually this is done automatically from the run loop. On background threads there is (usually) no run loop, so you have to create the transaction yourself:

```
- (void)orangeGradient: (UILabel *)fillLabel {
    @synchronized([CommonClass class]) {
        [CATransaction begin];
        CAGradientLayer * gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        gradientLayer.frame = fillLabel.bounds;
        gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColorFromRGB(0xfbb250) CGColor],(id)[UIColorFromRGB(0xf47c2a) CGColor], nil];
        [fillLabel.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
        [CATransaction commit];
    }
}
```

There's another issue: UIKit is not thread safe. You can't call `bounds` on a `UILabel` on a background thread.

Comment: or should I call this method using `performSelectorInMainThread:` ?

Comment: @NikitaP Yes, if you use a UILabel you are bound to the main thread anyway. So you can get rid of the `@synchronized` as well.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe this makes sense. +1 for this but she is already calling this function in main thread so offcourse updating label from background thread is not a problem but I guess explicitly putting CATTransaction should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Check anywhere in your code there is an ***uncommitted*** `CATransaction`. You will need to perform this operation following way;

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
[commonClassObject orangeGradient:lblFill];
[CATransaction commit];
```

[EDIT]

Basically this problem happens when NSOperation completes before CoreAnimation is done performing. There must be some relation between these two class in somewhere in your code you need to figure that out.

Comment: Warning message clearly says that the problem is uncommitted CATransaction. Please post your code from where you calling this method.

Comment: It's just a call like:
    UILabel *lblFill = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake (0,0,100,30)];
    [commonClassObject orangeGradient:lblFill];

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add that I had the same problem with initWithFrame from a background threads.

Seems that since iOS 7 and upwards, some calls to UIKit must be done under the main thread, and cannot be called from a background thread.

Also note that after several warnings like this, my app stopped responding completely. So better not ignore such warning.